# angularjs form wizard validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, formwizard

So I depending the link to the next step using `ng-form` directive. But I found out that the other link to the next steps except the current one is `enabled`.

So I changed it to use flag for `ng-disabled` . here is my code:

***index.html***

```
<div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ui-sref="step1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="step1Form.$invalid;" ui-sref="step2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="step2Disabled;" ui-sref="step3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="step3Disabled;" ui-sref="step4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">4</a>            
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="step4Disabled;" ui-sref="step5" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">5</a>            
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="step5Disabled;" ui-sref="step6" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

***app.js***

```
$scope.step2Disabled = true;
$scope.step3Disabled = true;
$scope.step4Disabled = true;
$scope.step5Disabled = true;
```

But using this approach will not `enabled` the next step whenever the current step's form validation is valid. How do I solve this? thanks

**UPDATE**

I try this solution:

***test 1:***

```
<div class="stepwizard-step">
  <a ng-disabled="step3Disabled;step3Form.$invalid;" ui-sref="step4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">4</a>            
</div>
```

***test 1 result:***

it only works when Im in current step, the `ng-disabled` works when the form validation is valid

***test 2:***

```
<div class="stepwizard-step">
  <a ng-disabled="step3Disabled || step3Form.$invalid;" ui-sref="step4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">4</a>            
</div>
```

***test 2 result:***

When Im at previous step, the link to this step is perfectly disabled. But the link to next step is still disabled when Im at this step and the form is valid.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a $scope variable in your controller:

```
$scope.currentStep = 0;
$scope.enableCount = 0;
```

then you have a function

```
$scope.changeStep = function(index){
    $scope.currentStep = index;
}
```

in your submit function you add this line of code:

```
if(form.$valid && $scope.enableCount <= $scope.currentStep) $scope.enableCount++;
```

then in your html you should do like this:

```
<div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ui-sref="step1" type="button" ng-click="changeStep(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="enableCount < 1" ng-click="changeStep(1)" ui-sref="step2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="enableCount < 2" ng-click="changeStep(2)" ui-sref="step3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="enableCount < 3" ng-click="changeStep(3)" ui-sref="step4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">4</a>            
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="enableCount < 4" ng-click="changeStep(4)" ui-sref="step5" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">5</a>            
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a ng-disabled="enableCount < 5" ng-click="changeStep(5)" ui-sref="step6" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle active-step-wizard">6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I see you need it without a submit function.

Comment: hi thanks for answering :D but I think its only triggered when submitting the button. is there any method to enable/disable whenever the form is valid?

Comment: maybe you can do a watch for the validity of the forms, but it is computationally expensive. would think of another idea

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer Did you get the answer ?

Comment: I am not the original PO